# Is there something fundamentally wrong with using the same features/learning algorithm for the same data set given different labels?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have two ML algorithms trained to classify structured text documents in the following way:

Model 1: P(B|A) = score_x (trained over count(A) samples)

Model 2: P(C|B) = score_y (trained over count(B) samples).

In the overall process, a document can error and be put into class A. An analyst needs to look at all class A documents and determine whether its class B or not. Within class be, there are many finer descriptions of the class, but for the sake of ease the model classifies it is class C or not class C. C is a subset of B, B is a subset of A.

The models use the same features and have the same structure/parameters. The only thing that changed was the training set and labels for each model. Model 1 was fed all class-A documents with a B/notB label. Model 2 was trained over only class-B documents with a C/notC label. It seems to be better at classifying C|B (About 50% of B are class C, but only  about 15% of class A is B).

Is there something wrong with this approach? Should there only be one model that classified P(C|B)?

Comment: Can you please revise your question and elaborate your problem more? This is quite brief and not very clear to me.

Comment: I'll try to reword some things..